# Problem related to appending the objects in the serialization process

Tags: java, serialization, append, deserialization, writefile

when I enter the inputs as objects, they can be easily saved and able to read in the serialization process but when I add them a second time, objects which are added second time  saved in the file, but unable to read them .showing an error related to an invalid type code AC.

```
try (FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filename,true);
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file))
    {
        for (Product pro : productList) {
            out.writeObject(pro);
            System.out.println(pro);
        }


        System.out.println("Object has been saved successfully");
        productList.clear();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException is caught");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Read file code:

```
try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file))
    {
            while ( (p1 = (Product) in.readObject()) != null)
            {

                newProductList.add(p1);
                System.out.println(p1);
                System.out.println("done");
                System.out.println(newProductList.size());

            }
        in.close();
        file.close();
        System.out.println("Reached end of file.");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error while reading product data: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Class not found during deserialization: " + e.getMessage());
        }

          return newProductList;
}
```

Please help me fix this error.

I need a correct code to fix my problem

Comment: is that the code that is not working? Or just the one that is working? The later one will not help much solving the problem - better include a [mre] in the question. As seen on this site before, `ObjectOutputStream` constructor writes a header that is read by the `ObjectInputStream` constructor, the constructor calls must be paired, that is, opening a second `ObjectOutputStream` must also be reflected by opening a second `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: the header problem also affects if appending to a file, actually worse in that case: the reading code will not be able to know if a new `ObjectInputStream` is needed or not - Why not write the whole list as one object? Makes reading a bit easier... (assuming the list is Serializable)

Comment: Collections are mostly serializable. ArrayList and LinkedList are for sure. Why don't you just serialize the entire collection?

Comment: difficult to serilaize the entire collection

Comment: @YanujaThanabalasingam How exactly is it difficult? As long the collection is serializable, the serialization process will be - `out.writeObject(productList);`, no loops, no nothing.

Comment: ya that worked correctly,Thankyou